# choose which constructor in c++

Tags: c++, constructor, resolution

I am practicing C++ by building my own version of vector, named "Vector". I have two constructors among others, fill constructor and range constructor. Their declarations look like following:

```
template <typename Type> 
class Vector {
public:
    // fill constructor
    Vector(size_t num, const Type& cont);

    // range constructor
    template<typename InputIterator> Vector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);

    /* 
    other members
    ......
    */
}
```

The fill constructor fills the container with num of val; and the range constructor copies every value in the range [first, last) into the container. They are supposed to be the same with the two constructors of the STL vector.

Their definitions goes following:

```
//fill constructor 
template <typename Type> 
Vector<Type>::Vector(size_t num, const Type& cont){
    content = new Type[num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i ++)
        content[i] = cont;
    contentSize = contentCapacity = num;
}

// range constructor
template <typename Type> 
template<typename InputIterator>
Vector<Type>::Vector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last){
    this->content = new Type[last - first];

    int i = 0;
    for (InputIterator iitr = first; iitr != last; iitr ++, i ++)
    *(content + i) = *iitr;

    this->contentSize = this->contentCapacity = i;
}
```

However, when I try to use them, I have problem distinguishing them.
For example:

```
Vector<int> v1(3, 5);
```

With the this line of code, I intended to create a Vector that contains three elements, each of which is 5. But the compiler goes for the range constructor, treating both "3" and "5" as instances of the "InputIterator", which, with no surprises, causes error.

Of course, if I change the code to:

```
Vector<int> v1(size_t(3), 5);
```

Everything is fine, the fill constructor is called. But that is obviously not intuitive and user friendly.

So, is there a way that I can use the fill constructor intuitively?

Comment: By the way, if you capitalized `Vector` to avoid a name collision, you might consider putting your classes in a namespace… especially if this is for practice!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `std::enable_if` (or `boost::enable_if` if you don't use C++11) to disambiguate the constructors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


template <typename Type> 
class Vector {
public:
    // fill constructor
    Vector(size_t num, const Type& cont)
    { 
        cout << "Fill constructor" << endl;
    }

    // range constructor
    template<typename InputIterator> Vector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
        typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<InputIterator>::value>::type* = 0)
    { 
        cout << "Range constructor" << endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    Vector<int> v1(3, 5);
    std::vector<int> v2(3, 5);
    Vector<int> v3(v2.begin(), v2.end());
}
```

The above program should first call the fill constructor by checking if the type is an integral type (and thus not an iterator.)

By the way, in your implementation of the range constructor, you should use `std::distance(first, last)` rather than `last - first`.  Explicitly using the `-` operator on iterators limits you to `RandomAccessIterator` types, but you want to support `InputIterator` which is the most generic type of Iterator.

Comment: Using `std::distance` is also problematic, because it won't work with iterators which can only be traversed once such as `istream_iterator`. i.e. it will work with forward iterators but not with input iterators in general.

Comment: @interjay, generally for input iterators you'd want to write a specialization that copies the data to a temporary buffer first, and then allocates the internal buffer for the vector.

Answer (score 3):

Even `std::vector` seems to have this issue.

```
std::vector<int> v2(2,3);
```

chooses

```
template<class _Iter>
        vector(_Iter _First, _Iter _Last)
```

In Visual C++, even though it should match closer to the non templated case..

Edit: That above function (correctly) delegates the construction to the below one. I am totally lost..

```
template<class _Iter>
        void _Construct(_Iter _Count, _Iter _Val, _Int_iterator_tag)
```

Edit #2 AH!:

Somehow this below function identifies which version of the constructor is meant to be called.

```
template<class _Iter> inline
    typename iterator_traits<_Iter>::iterator_category
        _Iter_cat(const _Iter&)
    {   // return category from iterator argument
    typename iterator_traits<_Iter>::iterator_category _Cat;
    return (_Cat);
    }
```

The above shown `_Construct` function has (atleast) 2 versions overloading on the third variable which is a tag to returned by the above `_Iter_cat` function. Based on the type of this category the correct overload of the `_Construct` is picked.

Final edit:
`iterator_traits<_Iter>` is a class that seems to be templated for many different common varieties, each returning the appropriate "Category" type

**Solution**: It appears template specialization of the first arguement's type is how the `std` library handles this messy situation (primitive value type) in the case of MS VC++. Perhaps you could look into it and follow suit?

The problem arises (I think) because with primitive value types, the `Type` and `size_t` variables are similar, and so the template version with two identical types gets picked.

Comment: @jogojapan I am not sure what is happening, gonna try to read deeper.

Comment: @jogojapan It seems the non template constructor is only used in the case of complex value types. In primitive type cases the templated version correctly guesses the type of constructor based on some template specialization based on the type of the first `InputIterator` arguement

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the same at the one faced by the standard library implementation. There are several ways to solve it.

- You can meticulously provide non-template overloaded constructors for all integral types (in place of the first parameter).
- You can use SFINAE-based technique (like `enable_if`) to make sure the range constructor is not selected for integer argument.
- You can branch the range constructor at run-time (by using `if`) after detecting integral argument (by using `is_integral`) and redirect control to the proper constructing code. The branching condition will be a compile-time value, meaning that the code will probably be reduced at compile-time by the compiler.
- You can simply peek into your version of standard library implementation and see how they do it (although their approach is not required to be portable and/or valid from the point of view of abstract C++ language).

Answer (score 2):

This ambiguity caused problems for early library implementers. It's called the "Do The Right Thing" effect. As far as I know, you need [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE) to solve it… it might have been one of the first applications of that technique. (Some compilers cheated and hacked their overload resolution internals, until the solution was found within the core language.)

The standard specification of this issue is one of the key differences between C++98 and C++03. From C++11, §23.2.3:

> 14 For every sequence container defined in this Clause and in Clause 21:
>
> — If the constructor
>
> ```
>        template <class InputIterator>
>        X(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
>          const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type())
> ```
>
> is called with a type InputIterator that does not qualify as an input iterator, then the constructor shall not participate in overload resolution.
>
> 15 The extent to which an implementation determines that a type cannot be an input iterator is unspecified, except that as a minimum integral types shall not qualify as input iterators.